# Extract User's ID and insert into Posts table in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Experimenting with ruby on rails.. I put a new Post form on a users show page.(i.e. 0.0.0.0:3000/users/2) I'm trying to extract the user's id and insert it into a 'user_id' field in the Post table when you create a new post. So when the form is submitted from the user's page, I can link it to the user that wrote it.

models/post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  before_save :create_user_id

  def create_user_id
    self.user_id = current_user
  end
end
```

models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end
```

helpers/application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

controllers/post_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @page_title = @post.title.capitalize
    @author = User.find(@post.user_id)
    @author_url = "/users/" + @post.user_id.to_s
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.create(post_params)
    if @post.save
      redirect_to @post
    else
     render 'new'
    end
  end

  # private
  private

    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :user_id)
    end
end
```

The error I get:

```
Couldn't find User without an ID

Extracted source (around line #15):  
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @page_title = @post.title.capitalize
>>@author = User.find(@post.user_id)
  @author_url = "/users/" + @post.user_id.to_s
end
```

If I test and change my application_helper.rb to this it works, and inserts 2 into the Post's user_id field. The current set up just returns nil

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def current_user
    @current_user = 2
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you want to get the current user, for now you can test using something like this:

```
@current_user ||= User.find(2)
```

Note that there will not be an :id param available on a create call, :id refers to a specific member of your resource so in this case if get `http://localhost:3000/posts/1` posts would be the resource and 1 would be the param :id so this would not return the current_user you expected.

Then association should do all of the work for you and there is no need for the create_user_id method. All you would have to do is tweak your create method to

```
@post = current_user.posts.create(post_params)
```

Comment: Thanks, after changing to '@post = current_user.posts.create(post_params)'...'@current_user ||= User.find(2)' does work for testing, It links the new post to my user with an ID of 2 as expected, no errors. '@current_user ||= User.find(params[:id])' still returns an error. I see what you mean about it not finding the proper id, but I thought there would be a way to do this if the create new post form was on the users page? Is there a better way to do what I want?

Comment: You've certainly got the right idea. There are a number of ways this can be done, the simplest and most common of which is to create a session. This [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch) should help you out.

Comment: Ah, okay I see. So really the best/simplest way to get what I was after was to create a session with the user's ID. I got this working now, thanks for the help!